# Cannot instantiate an object in Jenkins Shared Library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, shared-libraries, jenkins-shared-libraries

Currently I am working on creating a Jenkins shared library in my project and facing a problem trying to instantiate an object.

Tree structure of my application
- day#1
-- ./Jenkinsfile
-- ./src/File1.groovy
-- ./test/File1Spec.groovy
-- ./vars/file1.groovy

From my Jenkinsfile I can call file1.function which inturn will create a class object written in the file ./src/File1.groovy and it works perfectly, But on day#2, I add one more class(src/File2.groovy) and tried to create an object in vars/file2.groovy and it fails with the following error:

> "com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsCallableInvocation"
>   "Finished: FAILURE"

- day#2
-- ./Jenkinsfile
-- ./src/File1.groovy
-- ./src/File2.groovy
-- ./test/File1Spec.groovy
-- ./test/File2Spec.groovy
-- ./vars/file1.groovy
-- ./vars/file2.groovy

Can anyone give me a clue how this can be solved?

/Prasanth

Comment: Can you show us what `src/File2.groovy` and `vars/file2.groovy` have inside?

Answer (score 7):

CpsCallableInvocation means that you called a CPS method like `echo` from within a `NonCPS` method or a constructor. Check your code for that.