# jenkins shared library error com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsCallableInvocation

Tags: jenkins, groovy, enums, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline

I run this code through jenkins pipeline(shared library).

```
enum Components {
  service('name_api')

  Components(String componentName) {
    this.componentName = componentName
  }

  private String componentName

  String getComponentName() {
    return componentName
  }

  static boolean isValid(String name) {
    for (Components component : values()) {
      if (component.getComponentName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
        return true
      }
    }
    println("The name of component is incorrect")
  }
}
```

It works locally, but in Jenkins pipeline, I get this error:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException:         
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsCallableInvocation
```

help me please

Comment: Can you provide [mcve]? You have pasted an enum, it says nothing about what is the shared library file you run and what is also important - how you run it (what method you are executing etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48932971/4279361

Comment: A problem solved. Problem was inside my constructor

Answer (score 5):

Something is wrong with groovy interpreter in that Jenkins. I'm trying to write a library and have the same error.

I made an example of pipeline script. I wrote different classes to avoid induced errors:

```
class Test1 {
    private t1
    private wfs

    Test1(Test2 t2, wfs) {
        this.wfs = wfs
        wfs.echo 'TEST1 constructor'
        this.t1 = t2.getT2() }

    def getT1() {
        wfs.echo 'getT1() function'
        def result = t1.toString()
        return result }
}

class Test2 {
    private t2
    private wfs

    Test2(wfs) {
        this.wfs = wfs
        wfs.echo 'TEST2 constructor'
        this.t2 = "hello" }

    def getT2() {
        wfs.echo 'getT2() function'
        def result = t2.toString()
        return result }
}

echo 'Creating Test2 object'
Test2 test2 = new Test2(this)
echo "Test2 object was created successfully. test2.t2="+test2.getT2()
echo 'Creating Test1 object'
Test1 test1 = new Test1(test2,this)
echo "Test1 object was created successfully. test1.t1="+test1.getT1()
```

output on this script is:

```
Started by user admin
[Pipeline] echo
Creating Test2 object
[Pipeline] echo
TEST2 constructor
[Pipeline] echo
getT2() function
[Pipeline] echo
Test2 object was created successfully. test2.t2=hello
[Pipeline] echo
Creating Test1 object
[Pipeline] echo
TEST1 constructor
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsCallableInvocation
Finished: FAILURE
```

The problem is in this string `this.t1 = t2.getT2()`. It turns out that `t2.getT2()` function could not be done inside constructor :(

And 2nd one - if you try return like this:

```
def getT1() {
    wfs.echo 'getT1()' 
    return t1.toString() 
}
```

It will fail...

Comment: here the answer - you can't use object's method in constructor https://github.com/cloudbees/groovy-cps/pull/83/files

Comment: Exception to wunt's comment: You can't call any _NonCPS_ methods from the constructor. Try annotating getT2() with @NonCPS. See [JENKINS-55113](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55113).

Answer (score 0):

As this is closely related and pops up in google on the top, I'm going to provide some additional infos to `com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsCallableInvocation`

I come over this when I used following constructor: (no errors locally in EclipseIDE, but jenkins complained with this useless error message not mentioning any code line)

```
class blubb{
  blubb(Name){      
      super(Name) // must be first in CONSTRUCTOR
      // no return from super! , nevertheless, last throws...
      println("This will never be printed inside of jenkins!") 
      someBaseClassFunction() // this line is not allowed but errors!
  }
}
```

Here this is the point where @wunt small but super usefull comment comes into play.

Answer (score 0):

When I face this error, I annotate the method that is failing with `@NonCPS` from [groovy-cps library by Cloudbees](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.cloudbees/groovy-cps) and solved!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, it was caused by a method call for the parameter of a constructor for a field, where the method call was dependent on a field that was only initialized in the constructor. Something like this:

```
class A {
    final def b = new B(method())

    final def param

    A(param) {
        this.param = param
    }

    def method() {
        return param.foo()
    }
}
```

I moved the initialization into the constructor and inlined the method and the issue went away:

```
class A {
    final def b

    final def param

    A(param) {
        this.param = param
        this.b = new B(param.foo())
    }
}
```

Comment: In your original class, you were calling an instance to initialize a field which gets executed before the constructor gets a chance to run so `param.foo()` would always cause an NPE in this case.